# Is there a way to write a string type array to a file?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file

I'm trying to write the content of a string array to a file without changing the way lines are displayed

```
  string voti = Convert.ToString(Properties.Resources.voti);

  string [] lines = voti.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

  voti = voti.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();

  string testo = Convert.ToString(lines);

  File.WriteAllText(voti, testo);
```

The output should be like this:

First Line

Second Line

Third Line

The actual output is:
First LineSecond LineThird Line

Comment: What is in `lines`? Shouldn't that be `string testo = Convert.ToString(voti);` ?

Comment: As @Vishnu points out below.. string withCRLFStr = String.Join("\r\n", array); ??

Comment: Why are you writing to a file named "System.String[]" (the contents of voti)?

Comment: Your edits are making this way more confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make much sense of your post, but to write an array of strings as lines to a file, use:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\myfile.txt", yourArray);
```

The first argument is the path, the second is the array of strings. They will be written to the file one line per array entry

A self contained example:

```
string s = "First\tSecond\tThird";                       //tab separated string
string[] sa = s.Split('\t');                             //split on tabs, to array
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\myfile.txt", sa); //write array as lines
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry i'm a beginner and i'll try to edit the post to make it understandable but you still helped me

Answer (score 0):

Make use of string.Join to create the string from List.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8